# JAVA - Sorting Speed of Multithreaded Mergesort

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing, mergesort

I've implemented a multithreaded MergeSort in JAVA and have tested the running time of the algorithm with a different number of threads. I'm running the code on a dual core processor and the algorithm runs the fastest with 4 or 8 threads. This doesn't make sense to me - I have two cores. Here is my source code.

```
public static void parallelMergeSort(int[] a, int NUM_THREADS)
{
    if(NUM_THREADS <= 1)
    {
        mergeSort(a);
        return;
    }

    int mid = a.length / 2;

    int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mid);
    int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mid, a.length);

    Thread leftSorter = mergeSortThread(left, NUM_THREADS);
    Thread rightSorter = mergeSortThread(right, NUM_THREADS);

    leftSorter.start();
    rightSorter.start();

    try {
        leftSorter.join();
        rightSorter.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    merge(left, right, a);
}

private static Thread mergeSortThread(int[] a, int NUM_THREADS)
{
    return new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            parallelMergeSort(a, NUM_THREADS / 2);
        }
    };
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] a)
{
    if(a.length <= 1) return;

    int mid = a.length / 2;

    int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mid);
    int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mid, a.length);

    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);

    merge(left, right, a);
}


private static void merge(int[] a, int[] b, int[] r)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while(i < a.length && j < b.length)
    {
        if(a[i] < b[j])
            r[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            r[k++] = b[j++];
    }

    while(i < a.length)
        r[k++] = a[i++];

    while(j < b.length)
        r[k++] = b[j++];
}
```

I tested running it with a different number of threads and got the following results in milliseconds:

```
Serial Sort Run Time: 5368.
Parallel Sort Run Time with 2 Threads: 3202.
Parallel Sort Run Time with 4 Threads: 2408.
Parallel Sort Run Time with 8 Threads: 2544.
Parallel Sort Run Time with 16 Threads: 2738.
Parallel Sort Run Time with 32 Threads: 2909.
Parallel Sort Run Time with 64 Threads: 3078.
Parallel Sort Run Time with 128 Threads: 3777.
```

Why would this algorithm run fastest with 4 threads on a dual core cpu?

Comment: Do you have HyperThreading or similar?

Comment: We also really need to see the benchmarking code.

Comment: I think so but I'm not sure. My processor model is  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4258U CPU @ 2.40GHz but I can't find information on whether or not it supports HyperThreading.

Comment: This would have been entirely expectable if the inputs to the two-way-merges came from devices with mechanical delays. Now if your data was held in 12 [bubble memory devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_memory) … (back under my stone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why would this algorithm run fastest with 4 threads on a dual core cpu?

This could simply be an artefact of poor benchmarking.  For example, if your benchmark does not take proper account of JVM warmup effects, the results won't be reliable.

---

Beyond that, the "hyperthreading" explanation is plausible:

> Core i3, i5 and i7
>
> First introduced in 2008, the Core i3, i5 and i7 models constitute Intel's current line of desktop PC processors. They cover a wide range of clock speeds, from 1.2 GHz for the i3 Mobile to 3.6 GHz in the fastest i7 processors. All processors in the series are 64-bit designs and have a minimum of two cores each; **other than the quad-core i5 models, they all benefit from Hyper-Threading technology.**

Source: ["What Intel Processors Have Hyper Threading](http://science.opposingviews.com/intel-processors-hyper-threading-18298.html)?

However, the fact that HT is (apparently) available on your processor does not mean that it is actually enabled.  That will depend on BIOS settings, etcetera.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33450/checking-if-hyperthreading-is-enabled-or-not